# How to implement generic method approach using Linq and XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Alright, I think I have some duplicate code that can lend itself to the use of generics.

I have two different Xml files that I open, query, and return as collections that are bound to GridViews.  The collections are Lists of custom classes populated with data from the xml.  Each gridview has its corresponding custom class.  Currently I have two, and say the names of these classes are **XmlDataSource1** and **XmlDataSource2**.

Here's an example of what's working currently using the XmlDataSource1 as the example. Note that the constructor of the XmlDataSource1 object takes the XElements from the query and populates itself. Nothing crazy.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = GetXmlDataSource1(pathToXmlFile);
gv.DataBind();

public List<XmlDataSource1> GetXmlDataSource1(string pathToXmlFile)
{
   XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile);
   IEnumerable<XmlDataSource1> query = from s in xml.Descendants("NodeForXml1")
                                       select new XmlDataSource1(s);

   // Where clauses based on user inputs (deferred execution)
   query = query.Where(x => x.ID = SomeUserInputId);

   // More of these where clauses if they have inputs for them...

   // Convert to a List and return
   return query.ToList();
}
```

Now, to implement the GetXmlDataSource2() method, it's like 98% the same.  The major differences are, of course, the select portion of the linq query creating new instances of XmlDataSource2 object, the *"NodeForXml2"* descendants target node, and some where clauses that apply/do not apply.

How can I make these GetXmlDataSource# methods generic?  Ideally I'd like to call it as stated below and here's what I've tried but I can't get the select portion of the linq query to call the constructor of the correct data object.

```
GridView gv1 = new GridView();
GridView gv2 = new GridView();

gv1.DataSource = GetXmlDataSource<XmlDataSource1>(pathToXmlFile);
gv2.DataSource = GetXmlDataSource<XmlDataSource2>(pathToXmlFile);

gv1.DataBind();
gv2.DataBind();

public List<T> GetXmlDataSource<T>(string pathToXmlFile)
{
   // The type of T in case I need it
   Type typeOfT = typeof(T);

   XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile);

   // How to make new XmlDataSource1 and 2 objects?? This statement doesn't work.
   IEnumerable<T> query = from s in xml.Descendants("NodeForXml1")
                          select new T(s);



   // How to return the IEnumerable query to a List of the T's?
   return query.ToList();
}
```

How far away am I?  Am I close?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "I can't get the select portion of the linq query to call the constructor of the correct data object"...? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Yeah, I was getting an exception as that wasn't calling the corresponding constructor for the passed in T.  I've implemented the approach mentioned below from AirL and that gets those constructors fired.  However, I'm reading about the possible performance issues now to see if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/wcxyzt4d.aspx)

```
   IEnumerable<T> query = from s in xml.Descendants("NodeForXml1")
                                       select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfT, s);
```

But beware of performance issues, [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/22/optimization-and-generics-part-1-the-new-constraint.aspx) is a great post from Jon Skeet dealing with it :

> Apparently, that's slower than calling a delegate - presumably due to
>   trying to find an accessible constructor with reflection, and invoking
>   it

So if performance is a requirement, it would be better to pass a delegate to your `GetXmlDataSource1` method and use it to create the instance your need in your Linq query.

About your need to access XmlDataSources commons properties into `GetXmlDataSource<T>` method, you have at least 2 solutions :

**1** : Create an interface containing common properties :

```
public interface IXmlDataSource
{
    string ID { get; set; }   
    string CommonProperty1 { get; set; }   
    string CommonProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

This one would be implemented by your XmlDataSources. Here is a typical implementation :

```
public class XmlDataSource1 : IXmlDataSource
{
    public string ID { get; set; }   
    public string CommonProperty1 { get; set }    
    public string CommonProperty2 { get; set }

    ... // the rest of your code
}
```

Finally, [constraining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) `T` type would grant you access to these properties when you need them in `query = query.Where(x => x.ID = SomeUserInputId);`

```
public List<T> GetXmlDataSource<T>(string pathToXmlFile) where T : IXmlDataSource
```

**2** : A delegate could also do the trick, here is a typical call in this case :

```
GetXmlDataSource<XmlDataSource1>(pathToXmlFile, (query, result) =>
{ 
    return query.Select(e => new XmlDataSource1(e)).Where(x => x.YourProperty == value);
});
```

With a `GetXmlDataSource<T>` method signature that would look like :

```
public List<T> GetXmlDataSource<T>(string pathToXmlFile, Func<IEnumerable<XElement>, IEnumerable<T>> transform)
{
   // The type of T in case I need it
   Type typeOfT = typeof(T);

   XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile);

   IEnumerable<XElement> query = from s in xml.Descendants("NodeForXml1")
                                 select s;

   // Create and filter XmlDataSource1 instances thanks to the "transform" delegate
   return transform(query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo I've edited it and thanks.  I tried the Activator.CreateInstance() approach and that did execute their constructor.  Going to play around with it for a bit and see how the where clauses behave with this approach.

Comment: I must admit @D Stanley made a really good answer. Passing a delegate is certainly the best way to achieve what you need if performance is a requirement. The syntax remains quite light even if there is an additional parameter.

Comment: Any idea how I would access the properties of the T in where clauses?  For instance, in the OP: query = query.Where(x => x.ID = SomeUserInputId); I no longer have access to x.ID as it's not accessible in T?

Comment: You could create an IXmlDataSource interface containing commons properties that would be implemented by your XmlDataSources. Then the use of "where T : IXmlDataSource" in the GetXmlDataSource<T>  method signature would made these commons properties available in your Linq query.

Comment: Otherwise a delegate can also do trick (once again). It would looks like this one Func<IEnumerable<XElement>, IEnumerable<T>> transfrom = (query, result) => { return query.Select(e => new XmlDataSource1(e)).Where(x => x.YourProperty == something); }

Comment: Awesome edit, makes sense. I'm gonna fire these up when I get to the office tomorrow and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're close - one option is to have the *caller* pass in a function to create the instances:

```
public List<T> GetXmlDataSource<T>(string pathToXmlFile, 
                                   string elementName,     
                                   Func<XElement,T> factoryMethod)
{
...
   IEnumerable<T> query = from s in xml.Descendants(elementName)
                                       select factoryMethod(s);
...
}
```

Then the caller would say:

```
List<XmlDataSource1> list = GetXmlDataSource1(pathToXmlFile, 
                                              "NodeForXml1", 
                                              s => new XmlDataSource1(s))
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't get this to work. I'm getting an error on the "select factoryMethod(s)" call in the linq query stating that it has some invalid arguments.